# AppStore NavigationBar iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift

How is it possible to customize the navigation bar like in the AppStore app? 
I already tried to set the following (it is a subclass of UINavigationController):

```
    self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.with(color: UIColor.red), for: .default)
    self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.view.backgroundColor = .blue
```

Then the large navigationBar is blue and the small/collapsed navigationBar is red. But what I have to adjust that I get a translucent navigationBar when the navigationBar is collapsed?

[image: AppStore light large navigation bar]
[[image: AppStore dark small navigation bar[2]]
[image: AppStore dark large navigation bar]
[image: AppStore light small navigation bar]

Comment: Did you solve it by chance?